# Getting "Unexpected End of XML Document exception" from Item.Load() via Exchange Web Services(EWS 2.0)

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices, xmlserializer

I've done extensive research but can't seem to find the correct solution. This Exception only seems to occur about 50% of the time and it's when working with Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0.

The Exception is "unexpected end of xml document" from the item.load() method.  I figure it has something to do with XML serialization.  Any ideas what it may be?

TIA

```
FindResults = Service.FindItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, SomeMailbox), View);

foreach (Item item in FindResults.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            item.Load();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this quite often randomly on different configurations. My researched showed two possible reasons (both confirmed and fixed in code).

First. Sometimes EWS errors come through as SoapException or WebException instead of normal EWS response with information embedded. I don't know why, however it help calling all the EWS methods through a wrapper where you can deduce what happened and sometimes rethrow something reasonable (sometimes you get EWS soap package with error details as a part of WebException).

Second. For some unknown reason sometimes responses are returned as not XML compatible with weirdo characters in the body. You just have to delete them before they reach the xml parser. I don't use Managed EWS library and just create a soap wrapper around exchange endpoint for many good reasons like this when it occasionally fails. In the wrapper just change base class from SoapHttpClientProtocol to your own, and override:

```
      protected override XmlReader GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize)
  {

     XmlTextReader reader = (XmlTextReader)base.GetReaderForMessage(message, bufferSize);
     reader.Normalization = false; // prevent checking for invalid xml chars in response
     return reader;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a right response without knowing how the xml document is, it's length and how are you testing your class but i can give you some clues:

- Check the length of your xml: check with different lengths because it's possible to get and overflow with a huge document
- Check the xml document availability: it's possible that the xml become unavailable in the middle of the loading process so that it would cause a fail
- Check the content of the xml: if always fails with same document and not with other it's possible your xml to have a problem with the encoding

Answer (score 0):

I see this using Managed API 2.1, but only very occasionally.  I've always written it off to some kind of network hiccup losing a bit of the XML.  It might be instructive to get a WireShark trace of what's coming in from EWS, or turning on EWS tracing, altho I'm not sure that you'd get the trace of malformed XML if it comes in that way.

At your 50% rate, it should be easy to catch this coming down and have grounds for opening an issue with MS Support.  You might also consider upgrading to the 2.1 API--should not require any code changes on your part, and might have this thing addressed in your particular case.